# How to authenticate the user with warden/devise in a customized way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

This is a Rails 3.0 app with Mongoid as ODM. Following is the user model in which the devise is installed.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  field :email
  field :username
  field :loginable_token

end
```

I'm building an API. So, for authentication I wanted to authenticate the users with :email and :password. From the GUI, its fine and working.

Now, I want to implement it via API, so I ve created a separate route `/api_login.json` that hits the `login` action with params `{"username"=>"kapil@gmail.com", "password"=>"sachin", "action"=>"login", "controller"=>"api/v1/accounts", "format"=>"json"}`

When I try to authenticate with the `warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)` method before `sign_in`, it blows up with the following backtrace.

```
(rdb:1) l
[3, 12] in /Users/sts-151sts-151/Dev/cloudfactory/app/controllers/api/v1/accounts_controller.rb
  3      respond_with(@current_account)    
  4    end
  5    
  6    def login
  7      debugger
=> 8      resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  9       sign_in(:user, resource)
  10      if user == nil
  11        
  12        respond_with(User.account.apps.first)
(rdb:1) p params
{"username"=>"kapil@gmail.com", "password"=>"sachin", "action"=>"login", "controller"=>"api/v1/accounts", "format"=>"json"}
(rdb:1) rs = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
*** Unknown command: "rs = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)".  Try "help".
(rdb:1) p rs = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)

 1) /api/v1/lines POST send back the default app
    Failure/Error: last_response.status.should eql(200)

expected 200
    got 401

(compared using eql?)

    # ./spec/api/v1/accounts_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test is via default `rack-test` way.

What is correct way to authenticate?

Comment: devise has a strategy named token_authenticable, which can be very useful for APIs, you should probably explore to see if that fits your needs.

Comment: Yeah! I know it has. But right now its not the option/change I can make.